# Foundation 5 - Top Bar not working on tablet and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

Here's a direct link of my site: http://jdfill.me/ (the code is too long to post here).

I've set up anchors and imported smoothscrolling.js for the navigation. What happens currently on the home page in desktop view (and it's perfect) is that when you click on Work or About, they simply scroll down nicely to their alotted areas. Works great.

On mobile and tablet, this doesn't happen.

On those smaller devices, the menus won't even open. I'm wondering if this is a problem with the JS not being called properly? I'm not too sure.

Any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: I can't even get the menu to open...?

Comment: Reloaded page. Its working fine?

Comment: It only works when you re-size your browsers on your desktop. However actually testing on a device (or Chrome's inspect tool in mobile), it doesn't work. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foundation 5 top bar not working on tablet or mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588686/foundation-5-top-bar-not-working-on-tablet-or-mobile)

Comment: if you are relying on superfish then look for a better menu solution, many superfish issues on SO